# Dojo to catch autocompleted event

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I've got a textbox that when text is entered, it will enable a button.  However, when the textbox is filled by the user selecting autocomplete text, the event doesn't get fired.

```
on(dom.byId('Textbox1'), 'keyup', function (event) {
                        if ((dom.byId('Textbox2').value.length > enable) && (dom.byId('Textbox1').value.length > 0)) {
                            domClass.remove(dom.byId('button'), 'disabled');
                            dom.byId('button').disabled = false;
                        };
                    });
```

Im hoping not to need a polling solution.  What I might do is use the mouse move events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a 'change' event listener.

```
var action = function(){        
    alert('fire');
};

on(registry.byId("login.username"), "change", action);
on(registry.byId("login.username"), "keyup", action);
```

See my working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrpno9bk/).

---

You code is also terrible. You want to use Dojo, but don't take advantage of it. When you want to use a value you have to use the `.get('value');` method. To get a widget you have to use the `dijit/registry` instead of `dojo/dom`.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for me.  I have to keep my asp:textbox objects and can't convert them to input type=text without blowing up other code...

Comment: Could you show me your full code? Normally an `asp:textbox` will be converted to `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but they are in an asp:Login control.  If I convert them into an input type=text, then in the code behind they are HtmlInputText which when used within an asp:Login control throws exceptions.  I can get the change or keyup events to fire.  It's that when the form controls are autocompleted, I can't catch the events.  I'm looking for a novel solution using Dojo.

Comment: @flux9998 My solution is a nice one(real Dojo). Could you show your full code? I guess you are using the wrong modules(`dojo/dom` instead of `dijit/registry`). Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: i tried it, but the 'dojo-data-type' tag wasn't friendly with the asp textbox :/

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding.  Of course I would use registry.byId if i were using a widget text box.  But I had a .net forms textbox that I could only access with dojo/dom.byId.  Not to mention the fact that I could have imported dojo/registry as 'dom'.  So before insulting my code, you should have clarified, especially considering that your fiddle is worthless for what i asked.

Comment: So did you finally manage to get your code working? Why can you only access a textbox with `dojo/dom.byId` when you are using ASP? Are you sure the textbox is already rendered? Otherwise it has to be possible to use `registry.byId`..

Comment: `dijit/registry` is for objects inheriting from dijit widget.  while `dojo/dom` is for DOM elements.  This text box is an asp.net control, so I would not be able to access it through registry.  The issue was when you navigate to a page that has login/password saved with autocomplete to where you just have to click a 'login' button, or when a password autocomplete feature is enabled on the browser, that it would get notified of the autocomplete filling in the password.

Comment: @flux9998 Aaaaahh.. I'm sorry. Now I do understand your problem. I will try to fix it for you. Side note: do you use the `dijit/form/ValidationTextBox` (and parse it)? Because you must be able to access it through the registry after it is rendered (`data-dojo-type` must be gone and a widgetid must be available. If you type `dijit.registry.byId(widgetid)` it can't be null).

Comment: @flux9998 What I currently do is performing an `onchange` when someone clicks the login button. This triggers Dojo to set the correct values.

Comment: can you give me a small example?